# Проверка числа при вводе scanf

Tags: c++, c

Вопрос такой:
Как считать с консоли целое число, которое влезает в диапазон `int`?
То есть, как обработать ситуацию ввода с консоли большой последовательности чисел которая не влезает в `int`?

```
scanf_s("%d", &n)
```

Вводим сюда `9999999999999999999999999999999999` например и получаем нестабильную работу программы.
Как с этим бороться?

Comment: а `scanf ` принципиально? для потоков например так можно `int n;  cin >>  n;    if (cin.fail()){    cout <<"InValid";    }` Возможно подобный метод и для `scanf ` есть, но сходу не вспомню.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не используйте `scanf_s()` используйте функции  `read() getc() fgets()` проверяйте введенный массив, а потом преобразуйте `int` в `char` используй `stroul()`

Comment: `gets` лучше не использовать никогда. Как альтернатива: `fgets`.

Comment: Согласен `scanf()` и `gets()` функции у которых нет ограничения на принимаемые данные, а это приводит к переполнениям и ошибкам.

Answer (score 1):

Тип int и правда платформозависимый. Размер int(и не только) для Вашего ПК можно узнать через функцию sizeof(). Она описана в stdio.h
Пример:

```
/* кол. байтов на данном ПК для разных типов данных */    
printf("int = %lu, float = %lu, double = %lu \n", sizeof(int), sizeof(float), sizeof(double));
```

Сравнивая размер вводимых чисел с размеров ячейки для Вашего ПК можно отсечь ИМХО ненужное (не int).

Comment: "а что делать если надо ввести два числа и сложить их, как потом проверить на переполнение? – perfect 12 часов назад"  Вы не можете складывать int и не int. Это не python :)   тогда или все int, или операция приведения типов (в вашем случае к высшему типу данных). А если оба одного типа, то складывая их Вы не получите переполнения никогда. Можете только данные потерять, если будете округлять для LF например. Поэтому деньги в банках не считают на чистом с.

Comment: scanf(форматная_строка, список_адресов_переменных) Форматная_строка - строка литерал, содержащая форматы ввода данных. 
Все символы, которые не относятся к форматам в форматной строке, будут восприниматься функцией как указание пропустить такие символы при получении информации. Функция  scanf не всегда может срабатывать, особенно при неправильном
вводе информации пользователем, поскольку такая информация не будет принята программой. Поэтому перед вызовом или после вызова этих функций рекомендуется вызывать функцию fflush, которая удалит оставшуюся информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Платформонезависивомого решения для языков С и С++ вы не найдете эти языки переполнение типа не считают ошибкой и исключительных ситуаций для этого не предусмотрено. Выход только один это писать свой платформозависимый обработчик на ассемблере, в процессоре для этого есть флаг переполнения в регистре флагов вот его то и можно использовать.

Comment: Однако, можете посмотреть на  ERANGE в [man strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)

Comment: а что делать если надо ввести два числа и сложить их, как потом проверить на переполнение?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже поднимался тут - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513736/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-c-c-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @perfect, лучше определять до операции, будет ли переполнение,  например, [так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514891/232)

Comment: @avp в самоучителе по которому я изучал язык было написано **если вы сомневаетесь будет ли переполнение то используйте более вместительный тип данных**, это наталкивает на мысль использовать тип **long double**. а про такие фишки я и не знал. так же я не могу понять почему для этого не придумали исключений. ведь в ассемблере эта ошибка явно определена как переполнение регистра

Comment: Видимо это не совсем правильный самоучитель (недостаточно глубокий), поскольку переполнение является ошибкой лишь с т.з. интерпретации полученного числа по правилам арифметики, а с позиции тасования битиков в конкретной архитектуре никаких ошибок тут вовсе нет. Что С++, что Си, предоставляют программисту некоторую свободу (хотя, в последнее время создатели компиляторов и вообразили, что им лучше, чем автору программы знать, чего он на самом деле хотел). А для надежного прикладного программирования, возможно, лучше выбрать другой язык.

Comment: со всем соглашусь, только вот с переходом на лучший язык вы явно поторопились, графику например кодят в крестах (все лучшие игры и движки на этом языке написаны), а это конек программирования как мне кажется.