# Как правильно возвести все числа не выходящие за пределы int в пятую степень, я написал но у меня переполняет помогите пжл

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits.h>

main()
{
    long i, x, y, z;

    for (i = 0; i <= LONG_MAX; i++)

    {
        printf("%d\n", x = i * i * i * i * i);

        for (y = 0; y >= LONG_MIN; y--)
        {
            printf("%d\n", z = y * y * y * y * y);
        }

    }

    _getch();
}
```

Вот код который я написал но видимо он неправильный
Задание:Напишите программу, которая находит все значения base^exp (base в степени exp), которые не выходят за пределы значений типа long.

base и exp - целочисленные переменные.
Для вашего варианта, значение exp = 5.
библиотеку math.h не использовать.

Comment: "Не выходящие за пределы int"? А почему тогда в коде `long`??? Откуда вообще взялся `long`?

Comment: Как-бы LONG_MAX по определению максимальное значение которое умещается в лонге. Поэтому даже LONG_MAX+1 не уместится в лонге, не говоря уже о том, чтобы пятая степень от LONG_MAX уместилась в лонге? Вам что надо сделать-то?

Comment: Минус вопросу за плохое оформление: код не надо прикреплять картинкой, его надо вставлять текстом.

Comment: Насколько я понял задачу, требуется в цикле возводить `i` в 5-ю степень до тех пор, пока не наступит переполнение. Т.е. вам надо после вычисления `x` проверить (например, делением в цикле), что переполнения нет (т.е. после 4-х делений `x` на `i` вы получили `i`). Как только нашли переполнение выходите из цикла.

Comment: @avp Вы правильно поняли задачу, но ваше решение совершенно неоптимально. Совершенно незачем что-то делить четыри раза и сравнивать с исходным числом. Посмотрите мой ответ ниже.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный, может я и ошибаюсь, но imho переполнение при умножении (в отличии от переполнения при сложении) может привести к неверному результату с **правильным знаком**. (сейчас попробую найти (вспомнить) ссылочку на алгоритмы определения переполнения)

Comment: @РостиславКрасный, [ловите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514891/232)

Answer (score 1):

При переполнении `signed long` (как и любого другого целого signed примитива) изменится знаковый (крайне левый) бит. Поэтому вы должны идти в цикле от 0 и до тех пор, пока результат пяти перемножений не станет меньше нуля. На Java это можно написать так:

```
    for (long n = 0, z = 0; z >= 0 ; n++, z = n * n * n * n * n) {
        System.out.println(n + "^5 = " + z);
        System.out.println(-n + "^5 = " + -z);
    }
```

На C/C++ вам надо лишь заменить `System.out.println()` на соответствующие вызовы `printf()` или `cout`