# Как сделать проверку на то, помещается ли значение в int?

Tags: c++

Вот программа, которая по сути выводит сумму первых N элементов вектора. Как выводить ошибку при попытке записи в int слишком большого числа? В данном случае в tmpint и в sum.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
try {
    vector<int> vals;                                       // Ряд целых чисел  
    int tmpval,                                             // Ввод целых числе
        sum = 0;                                            // Сумма первых sum_count элементов вектора vals
    int sum_count;                                          // Количество суммируемых значений, число натуральное

    cout << "Введите количество суммируеммых значений: ";

    cin >> sum_count;                                       // Ввод количества слогаемых с клавиатуры
    if (sum_count <= 0 || !cin)                             // Условие: число натуральное
        error("Введено неверное значение кол-ва слогаемых");

    cout << "Введите через пробел ряд (не менее " << sum_count 
        << ") целочисленных значений,\nдля остановки используйте любой символ, но не цифру: ";   

    while (cin >> tmpval)                                   // Заполнение вектора значениями    
        vals.push_back(tmpval);         

    if ((unsigned int)(sum_count) > vals.size())            // Условие: количество слогаемых не меньше количества элементов вектора vals
        error("Количество слогаемых не может быть меньше количества введённых чисел");

    for (int i = 0; i < sum_count; i++)                     // Счет суммы первых sum_count слогаемых
        sum += vals[i];

    cout << "Сумма первых " << sum_count << " значений (";  // Вывод количества значений, 
    for (int i = 0; i < sum_count; i++) {                   // самих значений и их суммы
        cout << vals[i];
        if (i != sum_count - 1) {
            cout << ' ';
        }
    }
    cout << ") равна: " << sum;
    return 0;
} 
catch (runtime_error &e) {
    cerr << "[ERROR] " << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Уже есть [ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514891/232) на [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513736/232)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В принципе проверка на переполнение очень проста. Если у нас два положительных числа, то сумма этих чисел не может быть меньше любого из двух слагаемых. И наоборот сумма двух отрицательных чисел не может быть больше любого из двух слагаемых.

Пример кода:

```
short sum = 0x7FFF;
short val = 1;

if (sum > 0 && val > 0 && sum > (short)(sum + val))
    std::cout << "overflow +";

sum = 0x8000;
val = -1;

if (sum < 0 && val < 0 && sum < (short)(sum + val))
    std::cout << "overflow -";
```

Вообще переполнение не является чем то из ряда вон. Это нормальное поведение бинарных чисел. И, с точки зрения разработки, нужно просто предусмотреть достаточную разрядность переменной для корректного результата. В Вашем случае это например может быть тип `long long`.

Comment: `Вообще переполнение не является чем то из ряда вон` — это верно только для беззнаковых целых. У знаковых же это неопределённое поведение, а потому компилятор на этапе оптимизации кода может спокойно сломать любое арифметическое выражение, полагающееся на переполнение.

Comment: @Arhad В более ранних стандартах написано было так `If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: most existing implementations of C++ ignore integer overflows.`, что лично я всегда читал так "Коммисия по стандартизации считает, что переполнение это неопределенное поведение, но разработчики трансляторов это игнорируют". Я согласен с разработчиками трансляторов. И хотя примечание убрали, трансляторы остались.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [SafeInt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/safeint-library?view=vs-2017):

```
#include <safeint.h>

try
{
    ::std::vector<int> vals{};
    ::msl::utilities::SafeInt<decltype(vals)::value_type> sum{};
    ::std::size_t sum_count{};
    ...
    {
        ::std::size_t value_index{};
        while(sum_count != value_index)
        {
             sum += vals[value_index];
             ++value_index;
        }
    }
}
catch(::msl::utilities::SafeIntException const & exception)
{

}
catch (::std::runtime_error const & e)
{

}
```

Comment: я может недопонимаю вопрос, но почему бы не сделать такую простую проверку : `if (val >= INT_MIN && val <= INT_MAX) {...}` ??

Comment: @ampawd Переполнение в знаковом типе является неопределенным поведением. Ну а вообще проверки можно поглядеть в реализации этой библиотеки.

Comment: @ampawd А значение может быть больше INT_MAX или меньше INT_MIN? Ведь если попытаться записать в int такое число, оно просто обрежется.

Comment: @Артем Переполнение в знаковом типе является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: как тогда эта библиотека обеспечивает всегда определённое поведение ?

Comment: @ampawd За счет оборачивания целочисленных типов в класс с перегруженными арифметическими операторами, которые выполняют надлежащие проверки. Эта библиотека еще и от деления на 0 защищает

Comment: Это понятно. Но я думаю что тут вполне можно обойтись ручной проверкой. А в этой библиотеке - куча оверхеда

Comment: @ampawd На счет "куча оверхеда" - это вы поторопились. Библиотека достаточно аккуратная и практически не дает оверхеда по сравнению с ручными проверками.

Answer (score 2):

Просто процитирую ответ с английского SO:

```
if (a^b < 0) overflow=0; /* opposite signs can't overflow */
else if (a>0) overflow=(b>INT_MAX-a);
else overflow=(b<INT_MIN-a);
```

---

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970802/test-whether-sum-of-two-integers-might-overflow

Comment: Оно же (переполнение *при сложении* знаковых) одним выражением `(((a > 0) && (b > (INT_MAX - a))) ||
      ((a < 0) && (b < (INT_MIN - a))))`  Хоть сейчас в `#define `