# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x000000013F6B212B в FinalHope.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00000000001C6000

Tags: c++

Я использую memcpy для того чтобы скопировать в bytebuffer информацию из массива.
Вот простой код:

```
char* bytebuffer = new char[1000000];
char* b = new char[2];
char* b2 = new char[2];
char* b3 = new char[1];
b[0] = '1';
b[1] = '2';
b2[0] = '1';
b2[1] = '2';
b3[0] = '1';
int dataindex = 0;
double time1 = -1;
auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
//int s = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        //s++;
        int size = 2 + 2 + 1;

            int ind = 0;
            memcpy(bytebuffer + dataindex , b, 2);
            ind = ind + 2;
            memcpy(bytebuffer  + ind + dataindex, b2, 2);
            ind = ind + 2;
            memcpy(bytebuffer  + ind + dataindex,b3 , 1);
            ind = ind + 1;

            dataindex = dataindex + size;



    }

}

auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> time_span = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t1 - t0);
time1 = time_span.count();
std::cout << time1;
```

Буффер может быть переполнен, из-за чего выскакивает ошибка:

"Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x000000013F4E212B в FinalHope.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00000000002D6000."

Вопрос: как можно перехватить это исключение?

Comment: Думаю ваш вопрос решён в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513736/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-c-c-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут возникает не исключение, а Неопределенное Поведение, которое, в свою очередь, приводит в возникновению SEH исключения, которое средствами стандартного С++ перехватить нельзя, да и не нужно, вместо этого вам необходимо устранить в свой программе выход за пределы массива.