# Проверка переполнения в сложении чисел

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Требуется вернуть 1, если переполнение после сложения чисел x и y не произошло, иначе 0.

Использовать можно только битовые операции: `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`.
`if`, `for` использовать нельзя.

Программа проходит не все тесты:

```
int addOK(int x, int y)        
{
    return (!(((x + y) >> 31) & 1)) & ((!(x >> 31)) & 1)  & ((!(y >> 31)) & 1);
}
```

Как исправить ошибки в коде?

Comment: Странное ограничение на операции сравнения. Если с ними, то [тут разобрана эта тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514891/232)

Comment: Ни `+`, ни `!` не относятся к битовым.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде бы такое должно работать:

```
int test(int a, int b)
{
    return ((((a+b)^a)&((a+b)^b))>>31)&1;
}
```

По крайней мере, тесты от Qwertiy проходит :)

Не используя явное `x+y` -

```
int test(int x, int y)
{
    return (((~(x^y)&0x80000000)&~(((x^(~(x^y)&0x80000000))+y)^y))>>31)&1;
}
```

Скобок мог и лишних навертеть :))

Во что это превратил VC++2017:

```
; 22   :     return (((~(x^y)&0x80000000)&~(((x^(~(x^y)&0x80000000))+y)^y))>>31)&1;

    mov ecx, edi
    xor ecx, esi
    not ecx
    mov edx, ecx
    shr ecx, 31
    and edx, -2147483648            ; 80000000H
    xor edx, edi
    add edx, esi
    xor edx, esi
    not edx
    shr edx, 31
    and edx, ecx
```

Так что - исходя из действий оптимизатора - можно так:

```
return (~(((~(x^y)&0x80000000^x)+y)^y)>>31) & (~(x^y) >> 31);
```

Comment: В общем случае знаковые нельзя складывать (возможно возникнет переполнение), а потом проверять.

Comment: @avp Так мы и проверяем - возникло или нет... Или вы о том, что *теоретически* при этом может быть сгенерировано прерывание?

Comment: Да, например, прерывание. Откровенно говоря, ни разу на практике такого не видел, но в теории это возможно. Поэтому для всей арифметики [рекомендуют](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow) сначала проверить, а уже потом вычислять. (там примеры для сложения, вычитания и т.д.)

Comment: @avp Ну, тогда с помощью зубила, какой-то матери и Уоррена - см. второй вариант...

Comment: Ага, или все же разрешить сравнивать, тогда `return (((y > 0) && (x > INT_MAX - y)) ||  ((y < 0) && (x < (INT_MIN - y))))`  (машинный код наверное вдвое короче)

Comment: @avp Машинный код - это вообще что-то особенного... Привожу в ответе...

Comment: `add edx, esi` -- вот тут нужно доказательство, что предыдущие манипуляции исключают возможное переполнение

Comment: @avp В том, как написано - исключают..

Comment: Может я плохо в уме моделирую x86 ALU, но для одинаковых `x = y = 0x7fffffff` (`edi == esi == INT_MAX`) у меня `edx = 0` перед `xor edx, edi`. Т.е. получаем **перед add**  `edx = INT_MAX` и `esi = INT_MAX`. // где я ошибся?

Comment: Код не проходит тест на входных числах 0x80000000; 0x80000000
Так же как и моя программа

Comment: Ну, вообще-то вот - https://ideone.com/UKwC9J, т.е. наличиствует переполнение. А его не должно быть? Это же два числа -2147483648. Сложите - они никак в `int` не влезут :) Ваша программа и в самом деле говорит, что переполения нет... - https://ideone.com/ykYthG (ваш столбец тут первый...)

Comment: Это решение обрабатывает случаи верно)) просто выводились 1 и 0 наоборот, поэтому не проходились тесты

Comment: Не пора ли вам принять решение, есть тут среди двух ответов верный, и принять его как таковой, птичкой слева от ответа?...

Answer (score 3):

Вроде бы так:

```
!((a^b)&0x80000000)&!!(((a+b)^(a&b))&0x80000000)
!((a^b)&0x80000000)&!(((a+b)^~(a&b))&0x80000000)
!(((a^b)|((a+b)^~(a&b)))&0x80000000)
```

Проверка:

```js
for (var f of [
  (a,b)=>!((a^b)&0x80000000)&!!(((a+b)^(a&b))&0x80000000),
  (a,b)=>!((a^b)&0x80000000)&!(((a+b)^~(a&b))&0x80000000),
  (a,b)=>!(((a^b)|((a+b)^~(a&b)))&0x80000000),
]) {
  console.log([[0,0], [100,1000], [-100,1000], [-100,1000], [-100,-1000], [2**30,2**30-1], [-(2**30),-(2**30)], [2**30,2**30], [2**30+8,2**30-2]].map(a=>+f(...a))+"")
}
```

Хотя и не соответствует стандарту, сначала сложить, а потом проверять.