# Реализация логического сдвига вправо

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Стоит задача: реализовать логический сдвиг вправо, используя битовые операции (~ & ^ |  << >>) и операции ! +
Программа не проходит все тесты

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n)
{
    return ((x >> n) ^ ((1 << 31) >> n)) & (~0);
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку и исправить ее

Comment: так вроде >> и << и есть логический сдвиг тудым-сюдым

Comment: Брр... Можно использовать `>>` для реализации `>>`? Или я не понимаю, что значит "логический" сдвиг? И раз уж вы так часто спрашиваете - то не ли URL вашей проверялки? А то вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1089199/195342) вы утверждаете, что мой способ не работает, и дальше все - ни ответа, ни привета, но мой вам ответ молчите...

Comment: `>>` и есть «логический сдвиг вправо» о_О...

Comment: для signed int по дефолту при >> производится арифметический сдвиг, т.е. для отрицательного числа при сдвиге вправо буду добавляться 1, а нужно, чтобы приходили 0

Comment: Подождите, вы просто хотите получить беззнаковый сдвиг, используя знаковый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить беззнаковый сдвиг, используя знаковый, то

```
int lShift(int x, int n)
{
    return int(((unsigned int)x) >> n);
}
```

Шутка, но работающая.

Ладно, попробуйте это:

```
int sShift(int x, int n)
{
    return (x >> n) & (0xFFFFFFFF >> n);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) у вас такие красивые и простые решения. Как научиться их видеть? Я все время усложняю

Comment: Очень много почерпнул из книги [Уоррена](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1838-3.html)/ Если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый (птичка слева от ответа).

Comment: _UINT_MAX_ лучше использовать вместо константы.