# INT_MIN * INT_MIN = 0 (c)

Tags: c, int, overflow

почему минимальный инт в квадрате равен нулю?

Comment: `(MIN_INT * MIN_INT) > MAX_INT`.

Comment: Стандарт разрешает это. почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513736/Можно-ли-на-языках-c-c-определить-целочисленное-переполнение

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`INT_MIN * INT_MIN` вызывает *целочисленное переполнение*, а переполнение знаковых типов Си — это *неопределённое поведение* (*UB*, *undefined behaviour*), что может дать любой результат — `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`, `0` или, например, `42`.

---

На практике на подавляющем большинстве архитектур сегодня отрицательные числа представляются дополнительным кодом, а после выполнения арифметических действия с ними результат, выходящий, за пределы регистра просто отбрасывается. В данном случае вычисления будут выглядеть как-то так:

```
                  доп. код  знак           прям. код
  INT_MIN     0x 8000 0000 => 1            8000 0000
* INT_MIN     0x 8000 0000 => 1            8000 0000
 -----------------------------v--vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
  INT_MIN^2                   0  4000 0000 0000 0000
              0x 0000 0000 <= 0            0000 0000
```

Но полагаться на это, конечно, нельзя. Алгоритм вычислений конкретного процессора может отличаться, а компилятор вправе сделать вместо этого вообще что угодно.

Answer (score 4):

потому что минимальный `INT` - это `-2147483648` или в бинарном виде

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

квадрат этого числа:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000
```

но если у нас 32битная система, то тогда квадрат равен...

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000
```

что и равно 0

если бы вы выполнили код

```
__int64 x = -2147483648;
__int64 y = x * x;
```

то конечно никакого нуля вы бы не получили, а получили бы `4611686018427387904`